# The Significance of Suffix -CE

Tags: enclitic

Allen & Greenough p.364, Note 2: the dative plural "his" has a suffix "-ce" attatched:

"hisce omnis aditus ad Sullam intercludere"; (Cicero Pro Roscius Amerino 110.10) firstly, (A & G) have omitted some words, the full quote:

"hisce [aliqua fretus mora semper] omnis aditus ad Sullam intercludere" =

"[always relying on some delay], to shut these men from all access to Sulla (close to them [Latin: "his"] every approach)".

(The missing words are irrelevant to this Q., but I'm surprised that (A & G) would do this.)

I have looked at the readily-available Greek & Latin suffix charts, to no avail. Therefore, the significance of suffix "-ce" is, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a demonstrative particle. You can find that in the book on [page 67](https://archive.org/details/allengreenoughsn01alle/page/66/mode/2up/search/hisce) where they comment about **Ille** and **iste** having the same particle:

> **a.** **Ille** and **iste** appear in combination with the demonstrative particle
>   **-c**, shortened from **-ce**, in the following forms:

Below that, there's another note as follows:

> **NOTE 1.**--The appended - ce is also found with pronouns in numerous
>   combinations: as, **huiusce**, **hunce**, **horunce**, **harunce**, **hosce**, **hisce** (cf.
>   Sect: 146. N. 1), **illiusce**, **isce**; also with the interrogative **-ne**, in
>   **hocine**, **hoscine**, **istucine**, **illicine**, etc.

Comment: Thanks. And I thought it was just another suffix. Little wonder I couldn't find it.

Comment: And perhaps the most commonly seen _-ce_ word of all that shows the full form of the suffix: ***ecce!*** (which oddly is not included in their list).

Comment: In addition, the -c in all forms of *hic/haec/hoc* is from the same suffix/particle, I believe. (By the way, I am used to calling it a deictic particle.)